# How to set the property "Retina Display Off" programmatically?

Tags: ios, iphone, retina-display, vfr-reader

I have used an open source API (VFR reader) to create an iOS app that displays pdf files. Now I want to disable the Retina display in my APP. How can I Do this .

Please help me out..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `enableRetinaDisplay:NO` method for this.

Comment: Sorry I could not stop to +1 :(  resulting in the loss of great number **5,786**

Comment: Best and accurate answer ever :)